# How to delivered message from GCP push subscription to local PC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to delivered message from GCP push subscription to local device.
The device does not have a global IP address.

Is there a way to delivered message to local device from push subscription?

In addition, in the following document, it is written like this.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push

> The push endpoint must be a publicly accessible HTTPS address.

Comment: Do you have a public IP (even if not global, at least a public one)

Answer (score 3):

You can not recieve pubsub messages when you don't have public HTTPS endpoint.

If you just want to store the messages on your device, Load pubsub messages into GCS bucket, and download it.

Or you can use [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount GCS bucket as file system on your device for easy use.

Comment: Glad it was useful. And feel free to accept this answer by clicking check-mark.